# Multiple entries in one column changing output in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF as shown below.

```
DF_Old =
ID NER   tID POS  token     R
1  B-ORG 1   NNP  univesity "OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash"
1  I-ORG 1   IN   of        "OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash"
1  I-ORG 1   NNP  washington"OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash"
1  I-ORG 1   NNP  seismology"OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash"
1  L-ORG 1   NNP  lab       "OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash"
1  U-LOC 22  NNP  wash      "OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash"
```

All columns should be pretty self-explaining except column `R`. This column contains the label of the row (OrgBased_In) with its direction. Meaning the characters after the "+" and before the "*" belong to the first argument and the characters after the "*" belong to the second argument. I now want to filter that vital information (and the Label of the NER) into a new column `Relations`.

I perfomed many necessary steps to get my desired DF

```
DF["Re"]= DF.R.str.findall(r"(Kill|Live_In|Located_In|OrgBased_In|Work_For)\+").str.join(',')
DF["Re"]= DF["Re"].str.split(',').apply(set).str.join(',')
DF["Argument1"] = DF["R"].str.split('+').str[+1]
DF["Argument1"] = DF["Argument1"].str.split('*').str[0]
DF["Argument2"] = DF["R"].str.split('*').str[-1]
DF["Argument2"] = DF["Argument2"].str.split(',').str[0]
DF["Argument1"] = DF["Argument1"].fillna("N")
DF["Argument2"] = DF["Argument2"].fillna("N")

conditions = [[x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(DF['token'].replace("-\d[\d]*","", regex=True), DF['Argument1'])], 
              [x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(DF['token'].replace("-\d[\d]*","", regex=True), DF['Argument2'])]]
choices = ["ARG1", "ARG2"]

DF["ARG"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default="O")
DF["Re"] = used_testing_global["Re"].str.split(',').str[0]
DF["Relations"] = DF["Re"] + "-" + DF["ARG"] + "-" + DF["NER"].str.split("-").str[0]
```

And dropping all unnecessary columns I get this (correct) result:

```
DF_New =
ID NER   tID POS  token      Re           ARG      Relations
1  B-ORG 1   NNP  univesity  OrgBased_In  ARG1     OrgBased_In-ARG1-B
1  I-ORG 1   IN   of         OrgBased_In  ARG1     OrgBased_In-ARG1-I
1  I-ORG 1   NNP  washington OrgBased_In  ARG1     OrgBased_In-ARG1-I
1  I-ORG 1   NNP  seismology OrgBased_In  ARG1     OrgBased_In-ARG1-I
1  L-ORG 1   NNP  lab        OrgBased_In  ARG1     OrgBased_In-ARG1-L
1  U-LOC 22  NNP  wash       OrgBased_In  ARG2     OrgBased_In-ARG2-U
```

However I got new Data into the DF which has more than one entry and thus more labels in the column `R`.

```
DF_2 =
ID NER   tID POS  token     R
1  B-ORG 1   NNP  univesity "OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash",,Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab."
1  I-ORG 1   IN   of        "OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash",,Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab."
1  I-ORG 1   NNP  washington"OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash",,Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab."
1  I-ORG 1   NNP  seismology"OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash",,Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab."
1  L-ORG 1   NNP  lab       "OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash",,Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab."
1  U-LOC 22  NNP  wash      "OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash",,Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab."
1  B-Peop 25 NNP chris     ",Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab."
1  L-Peop 25 NNP jonientz-trisler",Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab."
```

As you see, the structure is the same with ",," being the delimiter of the two parts. It is also possible that the data contains more than 2 entries in the column `R`. My code is not able to realise those are two different relations and thus the result is false.

```
DF_2_Expected =
ID NER   tID POS  token      Re                     ARG       Relations
1  B-ORG 1   NNP  univesity  OrgBased_In,Work_For   ARG1,ARG2 OrgBased_In-ARG1-B, Work_For-ARG2-B
1  I-ORG 1   IN   of         OrgBased_In,Work_For   ARG1,ARG2 OrgBased_In-ARG1-I, Work_For-ARG2-I
1  I-ORG 1   NNP  washington OrgBased_In,Work_For   ARG1,ARG2 OrgBased_In-ARG1-I, Work_For-ARG2-I
1  I-ORG 1   NNP  seismology OrgBased_In,Work_For   ARG1,ARG2 OrgBased_In-ARG1-I, Work_For-ARG2-I
1  L-ORG 1   NNP  lab        OrgBased_In,Work_For   ARG1,ARG2 OrgBased_In-ARG1-L, Work_For-ARG2-L
1  U-LOC 22  NNP  wash       OrgBased_In            ARG2      OrgBased_In-ARG2-U
1  B-Peop25  NNP  chris      Work_For               ARG1      Work_For-ARG1-B
1  L-Peop25  NNP  jonientz-trisler Work_For         ARG1      Work_For-ARG1-L
```

What I got insted:

```
DF_2_Got =
ID NER   tID POS  token      Re                     ARG       Relations
1  B-ORG 1   NNP  univesity  OrgBased_In            ARG1 OrgBased_In-ARG1-B
1  I-ORG 1   IN   of         OrgBased_In            ARG1 OrgBased_In-ARG1-I
1  I-ORG 1   NNP  washington OrgBased_In            ARG1 OrgBased_In-ARG1-I
1  I-ORG 1   NNP  seismology OrgBased_In            ARG1 OrgBased_In-ARG1-I
1  L-ORG 1   NNP  lab        OrgBased_In            ARG1 OrgBased_In-ARG1-L
1  U-LOC 22  NNP  wash       OrgBased_In            ARG2      OrgBased_In-ARG2-U
1  B-Peop25  NNP  chris      Work_For               ARG1      Work_For-ARG1-B
1  L-Peop25  NNP  jonientz-trisler Work_For         ARG1      Work_For-ARG1-L
```

I have not been able to change my code to get the expected output. What do I need to do? Any ideas?

Edit: Would it be wise to split the row based on the delimiter ",,"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following if you want to stay in the pandas flow -

```
a = 'OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash",,Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab.'
b = ',Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab.'
c = ['university', 'of', 'washington', 'seismology', 'lab', 'wash', 'chris']

df = pd.DataFrame({'NER': ['B-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'U-LOC', 'B-PEOP'],
               'R': [a, a, a, a, a, a, b], 'token' : c})

def function(df):
    temp = list(filter(None, re.split(',', df[1])))
    temp1 = temp.copy()
    for i, x in enumerate(temp1):
        if df[2] not in re.split(r'[ `\=~!@#$%^&*()_+\[\]{};\'\\:"|<,./<>?]', x):
            del temp[i]
    relations = [x.split('+')[0] for x in temp]
    temp2 = ['-ARG2' if df[2] in x.split('*')[1] else '-ARG1' for x in temp]
    output = []
    for i in range(len(relations)):
        output.append(relations[i] + temp2[i] + '-' + df[0][0])

    return ", ".join(output)

df['Relations'] = df.apply(function, axis = 1)
```

**Explanation**

The first for loop is to remove entries from column R which don't match with the token. Similar to the 'wash' token in your expected dataFrame. The regex splits the entries and you may simplify it by keeping only the desired ones. For eg. I removed the `'-'` from it as one of the tokens have it.

Also, it may be possible to optimise the code further by removing variables and some more comprehensions.

**Output**

```
df.Relations
0    OrgBased_In-ARG1-B, Work_For-ARG2-B
1    OrgBased_In-ARG1-I, Work_For-ARG2-I
2    OrgBased_In-ARG1-I, Work_For-ARG2-I
3    OrgBased_In-ARG1-I, Work_For-ARG2-I
4    OrgBased_In-ARG1-I, Work_For-ARG2-I
5                     OrgBased_In-ARG2-U
6                        Work_For-ARG1-B
```

Comment: This is pretty sweet but this part "+ str(i+1) +" does not exactly what I need. I need to compare the token values with the arguments value so I know which argument to take. Here it just increments.

Comment: Ah, my fault. I didn't comprehend the question correctly. Am I correct to say then that if the token is within the `+` and `*`  of the R column then it is Arg1 otherwise Arg2?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Sometimes it happens that the token is part of both if the relation is the same, but those special cases can be omitted (as my model doesn't recognize them).

Comment: I had to change a few things but this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

With these problems, it's best to begin with your input strings and create a function in pure Python to apply your tansformation. Pandas string-based methods aren't particularly efficient, either, so you may choose never to Pandorize your algorithm.

So let's take a couple of examples:

```
a = 'OrgBased_In+university of washington seismology lab.*wash",,Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab.'
b = ',Work_For+chris jonientz-trisler*university of washington seismology lab.'
```

You can define a function split these generically using just `str.strip` and `str.split`.

```
def splitter(x):
    return [i.split('+')[0] for i in x.strip(',').split(',,')]

print(splitter(a))
['OrgBased_In', 'Work_For']

print(splitter(b))
['Work_For']
```

You can then use the splitter function with `pd.Series.apply`, followed by a list comprehension. Formatted string literals (f-strings), available in Python 3.6+, are useful here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NER': ['B-ORG', 'B-Peop25'],
                   'Relations': [a, b]})

df['Relations'] = df['Relations'].apply(splitter)

df['Relations'] = [', '.join([f'{k}-ARG{idx}-{j.split("-")[0]}' \
                              for idx, k in enumerate(i, 1)]) \
                   for i, j in zip(df['Relations'], df['NER'])]

print(df)

        NER                            Relations
0     B-ORG  OrgBased_In-ARG1-B, Work_For-ARG2-B
1  B-Peop25                      Work_For-ARG1-B
```

Notice we omit creation of a series denoting how many arguments exists. You can use `enumerate` within your inner list comprehension for this purpose.

---

If you aren't using Python 3.6+, you can replace f-strings with `str.format`, i.e. instead of `f'{k}-ARG{idx}-{j.split("-")[0]}'` use:

```
'{0}-ARG{1}-{2}'.format(k, idx, j.split('-')[0])
```

Comment: Alright this was very helpful! I'm quite aware of the fact that Pandas string-based methods are kinda slow but I have to learn a bit more about DF so I tend to use them. The rest of your code is pretty self-explaining. I can't use formatted string literals since I use Python 2.7 but I just have to find another way. Do you think I should use regular expressions here? Thanks for the reply, mate.

Comment: @ThelMi, I've updated with an alternative to f-strings. In my experience, regular expressions are less efficient than regular Python methods. For this particular problem, I also don't think they are necessary.

Comment: This splits the OrgBased_In (etc.) into single characters (O,r,g,..) and then concatenates them into the desired form: O-ARG1-B, r-ARG1-B. DF['ReL'] = [', '.join(['{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(k, m, j.split('-')[0]) \
                              for idx, k in enumerate(i, 1)]) \
                   for i, j, m in zip(DF['ReL'], DF['NER'],DF["Argument2W"])]. I suppose the error is in the enumeration but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Seems like you've added extra bits (what's `Argument2W`?) and misaligned `format` arguments. The example I gave has everything lined up, i.e. `'{0}-ARG{1}-{2}'.format(k, idx, j.split('-')[0])`.